# Перезапись строки с помощью другой строки, используя цикл for: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, циклы, for

Необходимо перезаписать строку используя ключ. В одном из вопросов находил решение по перезаписи необходимой строки, однако и такой метод выдает ошибку.

Как я мог бы, используя Питон, перезаписать строку 'splaintext' с помощью 'key'?

- `key` является аргументом командной строки - argv[1] (строка)
- `splaintext` - строка, вводимая пользователем

В итоге, если:

```
splaintext` = 'hello'
key = 'abc'
```

результатом будет: `'abcab'`

Код:

```
for i in range(len(splaintext)):
    for j in range(len(key)):
        if i == len(splaintext):
            break
        else:
            while True:
                symbol = key[j]
                splaintext[i] =  splaintext[:i] + symbol + splaintext[i+1:]
                i = i + 1
                j = j + 1
                if j == len(key):
                    j = 0
                elif i == len(splaintext):
                    break
```

Ошибка:

```
splaintext[i] = splaintext[:i] + symbol + splaintext[i+1:]
```

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример входных данных (`splaintext`, `key`) и того, что вы хотите получить в результате...

Comment: 'key' является аргументом командной строки - argv[1] (строка). 'splaintext' - строка, вводимая пользователем. В итоге, если 'splaintext' == 'hello', 'key' == 'abc', нужно получить 'splaintext' == 'abcab'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

cycle_gen = cycle(key)

res = ''.join([next(cycle_gen) for _ in splaintext])

print(res)
```

---

Вывод:

```
abcab
```

Comment: В принципе, можно упростить: `range(len(splaintext))` -> `splaintext`

Comment: @gil9red, отличная идея, спасибо!

Comment: Сейчас попробую, благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @YanFarba, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: @YanFarba, это `"prompt"` для входных/выходных комманд в `ipython`, которым я пользуюсь. Я убрал это из ответа...

Comment: @MaxU Благодарю за решение! Все работает